# Как закрепить картинку за правым верхним краем блока?

Tags: html, css

Привет!Я тренировался в верстке и мне нужно закрепить картинку за правым верхним краем блока как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Она уходит на задний план текста немного.Как такое реализовать?
Код без вставленой картинки

```css
.Bitcoin-main
 display: flex
.Bitcoin
 background-color: #fff
 border-radius: 10px
 margin-bottom: 60px
 &-input
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  flex-wrap: wrap
  div:first-child
   margin-left: 10px !important
  div:last-child
   margin-right: 12px !important 
  div
   margin: 45px 5px 20px 5px
   p
    font-family: "CircleBold"
    font-size: 17px
    margin-bottom: 1px
    color: #000000
    margin-left: 20px
  &-cont
   border-radius: 39px
   border: 1px solid #00b0e8
   &-spec
    margin-left: 50px !important
   span:first-child
    margin-left: 20px
    color: #000000
    font-size: 19px
   span:last-child
    color: #00b0e8
    font-size: 18px
    margin-left: 8px
    margin-right: 15px
   input
    border: none
    outline: none
    margin: 20px 25px 20px 5px
    width: 120px
  &-button
   background-image: linear-gradient(266deg, #00b1e7, #00e3ac)
   box-shadow: 0px 15px 20.8px 0.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)
   font-family: "CircleBold"
   font-size: 16px
   border-radius: 39px
   border: none
   outline: none
   padding: 25px 70px 25px 70px
   margin-top: 60px
   margin-left: 5px
   &:focus
    outline: none 
.Bitcoin-text
 &-paragraph
  display: flex
  align-items: flex-end
  margin-bottom: 25px
  span:first-child
   color: #00e3ac
   font-size: 25px
   margin-left: 25px
  span:nth-child(2)
   color: #272727
   font-family: "CircleBold"
   font-size: 16px
   padding-bottom: 3px
   margin-left: 10px
  span:last-child
   color: #272727
   font-family: "CircleRegular"
   font-size: 16px
   padding-bottom: 3px
   margin-left: 3px
```

```html
<div class="Bitcoin-main">
     <div class="Bitcoin">
      <div class="Bitcoin-input">
       <div>
        <p>You send:</p>
        <div class="Bitcoin-input-cont">
         <input class="Bitcoin-input-cont-spec" type="text">
         <img src="./img/-----14.png" alt="bitcoin">
         <span>
          <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div>
        <p>You get:</p>
        <div class="Bitcoin-input-cont">
         <span>$</span>
         <input type="text">
         <img class="Bitcoin-fix" src="./img/-----15.png" alt="PAYPAL">
         <span>
          <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div>
        <button class="Bitcoin-input-button">Exhange now</button>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Bitcoin-text">
       <p class="Bitcoin-text-paragraph">
        <span>
         <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
        </span>
        <span>5min 36sec</span>
        <span>time last transaction</span>
       </p>
      </div>


     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-position:top right;`

```css
body {
margin:0;
}
.full-size {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background: url(http://pngimg.com/uploads/bitcoin/bitcoin_PNG47.png);
  background-size: 100px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-size"></div>
```